# How to accept only Positive four digits in HTML

Tags: html, datepicker, angular8, angular-forms

I am using Angular 8 to get some data from forms. I need years, i.e , positive and four digit numbers only. The code is given below

```
    <div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Year of Passing</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input id="yearOfPassing" class="form-control" [formControl]="row.get('YearOfPassing')" type="text" />
     </div>
    </div>
```

Could you guys help me figure how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: in the input tag you can use `min="1000" max="9999" `

Comment: Sorry..Still it's taking negative values

Comment: Use validators in `FormControl` by making your desired  `validator`

Answer (score 0):

Easy one is to use

```
<input type="number" maxlength="4">
```

You should still use JavaScript validation as well as server side validation once the data is sent from the form.

Additionally as it is years (if you want age) you can also use min="1950" and max="2020" just mentioning it so that you get a proper range of numbers if you want.

Comment: maxLength worked ...now its taking only 4 digits..but still it accepts negative values.

Comment: Add min="0" if you don't want negative values

Comment: I gave that too..but still it doesn't make a change

Comment: Different browsers different story. That is where the 2nd layer of JavaScript validation will come in handy. Add JavaScript validations even if this one is there and also add server side validations after data is posted even if all validations are passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='number' min=1000 max=9999>
```

Instead of 9999 you can also use 2020 if future years are not to be included.

Comment: Still it is taking negative and numbers with more that 4 digits